# What is the meaning of 'divers' in Acts 19:9?

Tags: acts, kjv

> Acts 19:9 (KJV) But when **divers** were hardened, and believed not, but spake evil of that way before the multitude, he departed from them, and separated the disciples, disputing daily in the school of one Tyrannus.

"divers" was translated from τις (G5100) and in the KJV this translation occurs twice I am aware of. ([Blue Letter Bible](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G5100))

Was this a correct translation and meaning in the context of this verse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/divers?s=t), the English word "divers" may be defined as "(used with a plural verb) an indefinite number more than one." It's not a word we read of very often, but of course, the King James Version was published in the early 17th century when such words may have been more common. Today, we would simply translate the indefinite pronoun τινές<sup>**(1)**</sup> as "some."

Thayer notes (p. 627):

> (b) Plur. τινές, **some** (of that number or class of men indicated by the context): Mk. 14:4, 65; Lk. 21:5; Jn. 13:29; τινές are distinguished from οἱ πάντες, 1 Co. 8:7; 9:22. τινές with an anarthrous participle, Mk. 14:57; Lk. 13:1; ταῦτά τινες ἦτε, such (of this sort) were some of you, 1 Co. 6:11 [cf. οὗτος, I. 2 d.]; τινές with a partitive gen., Mt. 9:3; 12:38; 28:11; Mk. 7:1 sq.; 12:13; Lk. 6:2; 19:39; Acts 5:15; 17:18, 28, and often; foll. by ἐκ and a partit. gen., Lk. 11:15; Jn. 6:64; 7:25, 44; 9:16; 11:37, 46; Acts 11:20; 15:24, etc.; Paul employs τινές by meiosis in reference to many, when he would mention something censurable respecting them in a mild way: Ro. 3:3; 1 Co. 10:7–10.

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>**(1)**</sup> τινές is an indefinite pronoun declined in the nominative case, masculine/feminine gender, and plural number from the lemma τις.

**References**

Thayer, Joseph Henry. *A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament: Being Grimm’s Wilke’s Clavis Novi Testamenti*. New York: American Book, 1889.